# Get the browser details in php

Tags: php, browser

I'm working for a small website, in which I was asked to get the browser name of the client which is using the site at that time with the help of a php script.

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: Just googled browser name in php and got this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014621/browser-name-in-php

Comment: Just use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20561874/1570901

Answer (score 0):

Check [broswer Information](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php#101125). There is a `function getBrowser()`

Answer (score 0):

**Code**:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
?>
```

**Output**:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7) Gecko/20040803 Firefox/0.9.3
```

---

**Code**:

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] => ^mozilla/5\.0 (windows; .; windows nt 5\.1; .*rv:.*) gecko/.* firefox/0\.9.*$
    [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; ?; Windows NT 5.1; *rv:*) Gecko/* Firefox/0.9*
    [parent] => Firefox 0.9
    [platform] => WinXP
    [browser] => Firefox
    [version] => 0.9
    [majorver] => 0
    [minorver] => 9
    [cssversion] => 2
    [frames] => 1
    [iframes] => 1
    [tables] => 1
    [cookies] => 1
    [backgroundsounds] =>
    [vbscript] =>
    [javascript] => 1
    [javaapplets] => 1
    [activexcontrols] =>
    [cdf] =>
    [aol] =>
    [beta] => 1
    [win16] =>
    [crawler] =>
    [stripper] =>
    [wap] =>
    [netclr] =>
)
```